# Sort ember data

Tags: sorting, ember.js, ember-data

I have a model named variableDataPackages whose structure is as follows:

```
TM.VariableDataPackage = DS.Model.extend({ 
    name: DS.attr(),
    number: DS.attr(),
    variableData: DS.attr(),  
    vds:DS.attr(), 
    asset_id:DS.attr(),
    vdp_id:DS.attr(), 
    type: DS.attr(),
    description: DS.attr(), 
    vdpackage_id:function(){
        if((this.get("type.name") != "d")&&(this.get("type.name") != "u")){            
            return this.get("type.name")  
        } else {
            return this.get("type.name") + this.get("number");                
        }
    }.property("type","number")   
})
```

The display value is a computed property and the set of records contained within the store for this model is frequently updated/deleted/created.

I want to be able to sort the records based on the vdpackage_id.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Could you give a little mor context, where you want to use the sorted data? The answer my depend on that.

Comment: I want to display the data by the sorted order. Its's basically a list of records and I just want to display it on the page.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`Ember.SortableMixin`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.SortableMixin.html) on the controller (examples can be found in the [guides](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.SortableMixin.html)). This would enable you to sort for diffent keys and to make this dependent on user input.

Anywhere in your code you can create an [`Ember.ArrayProxy`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ArrayProxy.html). An example for a model hook (untested, just to show the idea) would be:

```
 model: function () {
  return Ember.ArrayProxy.extend({
            arrangedContent: Ember.computed.sort('content', 'props'),
            props: ['bar:asc']
         }).create({
            content: this.store.all('foo')});
  });
}
```

Comment: Sorry, just to be clear, this model has a has many relationship to the asset model. i.e asset has many variabledatapackages. And I want to be able to sort the variabledatapackage records based on the vdpackage_id(while I'm on the assets page). Is that possible?

Comment: If this means that you want to show an assets variableDataPackages in e.g. the `asset/show` route with the asset being the model, then you would add a computed property based on `model.variableDataPackages.@each` to the `asset/show` controller. In this case a `return model.variableDataPackages.sortBy('key') might be enough. But this is still much guesswork on my part. You might want to provide more code. Additionally, a working http://emberjs.jsbin.com might be helpful.

Comment: BTW, if Asset has a HasMany to this model, then this model should have a BelongsTo relationsship to Asset instead of the asset_id.